# In Sketch 3 how can I delete the excess of a shape like in Adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, sketch-app

If I merge to shapes together or use a mask in Sketch 3 I want to be able to select the 'excess' and delete. For example I have a rectangle and then I overlap a circle with it. Then I want to keep the original rectangle and the overlap part of the circle but not any part of the circle that is outside of the rectangle.

So basically to keep all parts within the rectangle only. This is easy to do in Illustrator with the shape builder tool, you just select any part and can remove it. Sketch 3 seems to only have four options with shape combinations - none of which achieve this result.

I prefer Sketch 3 in every other way but its just missing this feature it seems.

Comment: Welcome Simon! Thanks for posting your question. Unfortunately, GD.SE is not designed to handle issues regarding technical support or basic software education. If you are seeking technical assistance with an application, please try the application manufacture's web site. If you are seeking to learn how to accomplish something within an application, please review the application help files or try an internet search with your question or an internet search for a tutorial. We are confident you will find answers.

Answer (score 3):

### Is it even necessary?

I get your question, but I don't think I understand the problem.

If you use a mask, you get the same result, but it's editable. The portion of the circle is masked and not part of the dimensions, but it's still there if you need to make changes.

[image]

### If you must ...

If, for some reason, you really needed to make the clipping permanent, you could use one of the other path combination tools.

1. Duplicate your shapes.
2. Use `intersect` to crop your unwanted circle.
3. Choose `Layer` > `Paths` > `Flatten`.
4. Position the result over the original rectangle, using the original circle as a guide.
5. Delete the original circle.

Not as elegant as Illustrator, but I'm not sure why it would be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

A great reason for doing this is for copying the SVG code out of sketch.

For those who just want part of the path:

1. Duplicate your group of shapes so still you have your original. (I made the original a symbol, copied it, and detached the copy from the symbol)
2. Use `intersect` to crop your unwanted circle.
3. Use `scissors` to cut out the parts you don't want.
4. Delete all layers unrelated to your new shape.